# Hand Wraps: How to wrap comfortably

Tags: technique, boxing, muay-thai, equipment

Are there any comfortable hand wrap styles for Boxing / Muay Thai ? I literally feel exhausted with wrapped hands and putting on my gloves everyday ( I wrap properly and don't wrap too tight), its always felt uncomfortable for the last 3 years doing this. Better to protect your hands, than break them I guess. I have preference for free-limb sports like basketball and gymnastics.

Just curious if anyone has thoughts how to prevent this issue? Its almost like sometimes I want to dare-say quit this sport, and do bare hands karate etc.

Comment: Is it the effort of putting them on? Too-tight wraps cutting off circulation? Muscles exhaustion from keeping your fists closed?

Comment: I think its just muscle exhaustion having them wrapped for 2 hours straight, its just not normal to the human body cc @MacacoBranco

Comment: Your hand wraps should not be causing you so much trouble. Without seeing you wrap your hands, my only guesses are that you are wrapping too tight and/or that you are clenching your fists and tensing your forearms constantly instead of only at the moment of impact. Try relaxing more. This is key to speed, endurance and reaction time.

Comment: Its more of no breathing and somewhat tight wraps,  however dont want to tight so much, I have my coaches wrap sometimes , same issue cc @Futilitarian

Comment: Well, the no breathing will exhaust you regardless of wrapping technique. Are you using elasticised or static wraps?